# What is the App Engine pull queue task life time?

Tags: google-app-engine, pull-queue

If a task is added to pull queue, how many days it will be in the pull queue? Is there any limit for task life time inside pull queue?

From google-app-engine docs, task can be leased up to maximum 1 week.

Does that apply for task life time too?

Answer (score 1):

In official documentation (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull) seems that the limit is 30 days:

> Maximum countdown/ETA for a task: 30 days from the current date and time

Comment: Thanks for giving reply. I have seen before but not sure whether this applies or not. May be this could be as there is no other maximum time period for task in pull queue.